# Firestore: How can I use a transaction to read and then write to a document that I don't have a reference to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document which i fetch with a query like this:

```
var myPromise = db.collection("games").where("started", "==", false).orderBy("created").limit(1).get()
```

I need to create a transaction where a read from this document and then write.
For example(taken from the documentation):

```
// Create a reference to the SF doc.
var sfDocRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

// Uncomment to initialize the doc.
// sfDocRef.set({ population: 0 });

return db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction.get(sfDocRef).then(function(sfDoc) {
        if (!sfDoc.exists) {
            throw "Document does not exist!";
        }

        // Add one person to the city population.
        // Note: this could be done without a transaction
        //       by updating the population using FieldValue.increment()
        var newPopulation = sfDoc.data().population + 1;
        transaction.update(sfDocRef, { population: newPopulation });
    });
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
});
```

I want to replace the sfDocRef variable with the myPromise variable but I can't since one is a document reference and the other is a promise.
How can I create a transaction on the document that myPromise represents?

Answer (score 1):

Once you actually execute that query, the reference is easily available. You can simply:

1. Execute the query as you are now
2. Find the [DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html) in the query results (as you normally would when handling query results)
3. Use the `ref` property of the DocumentSnapshot to get the document's reference, which is a [DocumentReference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html)
4. Use that reference in the transaction.

Comment: It seems like I am reading the same document twice.
Once when wait to evaluate the promise and once again when I "get" the specific document inside the transaction.
Is there a way that I can use only one network request instead of two?

Comment: The documentation for transaction.get() says that you can pass a reference or query to it.  Try passing a Query to it.  I honestly don't know if it's going to be any faster, and might actually be slower since you have to lock the document for the transaction, which means it could be executed more than once. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#get

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the promise to resolve, for example by attaching a `then` callback:

```
myPromise.then((querySnapshot) => {
  let ref = querySnapshot.documents[0].ref;
  return db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    return transaction.get(ref).then(function(sfDoc) {
        if (!sfDoc.exists) {
            throw "Document does not exist!";
        }
        var newPopulation = sfDoc.data().population + 1;
        transaction.update(sfDocRef, { population: newPopulation });
    });
  }).then(function() {
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
  });
});
```

This `querySnapshot.documents[0].ref` assumes that there's only one matching document, or that you only care about the first document. If there may be more you care about, you'll need to loop over the documents in the query snapshot.

You'll still need to `get` the specific document inside the transaction **if** (and only if) you want the transaction to ensure this document was unmodified between the query and when you write it in the transaction. If that is not needed, you can use the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` from the `QuerySnapshot`.

Comment: It seems like I am reading the same document twice.
Once when wait to evaluate the promise and once again when I "get" the specific document inside the transaction.
Is there a way that I can use only one network request instead of two?

Comment: Nope. The query is needed to get the reference, but can't be part of the transaction, so you'll need two reads in this case. This is one of the reasons why it's highly recommended to keep track of the document ID in your code.